# How to use python.h

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, file

I have included Python.h in my program,when i compile the program it shows multiple errors telling "Unable to open few libraries "
error message is as follows

```
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 7: Unable to open include file 'patchlevel.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 8: Unable to open include file 'pyconfig.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 9: Unable to open include file 'pymacconfig.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 50: Unable to open include file 'pyport.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 52: Unable to open include file 'pyatomic.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 63: Unable to open include file 'pymath.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 64: Unable to open include file 'pytime.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 65: Unable to open include file 'pymem.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 67: Unable to open include file 'object.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 68: Unable to open include file 'objimpl.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 69: Unable to open include file 'typeslots.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 71: Unable to open include file 'pydebug.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 73: Unable to open include file 'bytearrayobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 74: Unable to open include file 'bytesobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 75: Unable to open include file 'unicodeobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 76: Unable to open include file 'longobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 77: Unable to open include file 'longintrepr.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 78: Unable to open include file 'boolobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 79: Unable to open include file 'floatobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 80: Unable to open include file 'complexobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 81: Unable to open include file 'rangeobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 82: Unable to open include file 'memoryobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 83: Unable to open include file 'tupleobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 84: Unable to open include file 'listobject.h'
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 85: Unable to open include file 'dictobject.h'
Error E2228 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 85: Too many error or warning messages
*** 26 errors in Compile ***
```

and I did not include any of the above mentioned missing libraries in my program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Python.h>
int main()
{
     Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  
     Py_Initialize();
     PyRun_SimpleString("print("hello")");
     Py_Finalize();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling it?  It seems like you've copied just Python.h somewhere, but the compiler is not using the right _include directories_.  These are directories where the compiler will look for headers included by files.

Comment: The messages say "Unable to open include file"; there is no mention of libraries. (That's an important distinction since, as far as the compiler is concerned, libraries are things for the linker to deal with, and you're not getting that far into the compilation process.)

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
Error E2209 C:\Borland\bcc55\INCLUDE\Python.h 7: Unable to open include file 'patchlevel.h'
```

indicates that the error (unable to open file) was introduced by the file `python.h` in line 7. You might not have included all those header files, but your `python.h` might.

However,

1. try to find out where those files are stored on your computer. Then
2. find out how to tell your compilere where to search for additional include files and provide the location you found the files. Without doing so, the compiler just looks at certain pre-configured directories which are, in your case, not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> I did not include any of the above mentioned missing libraries in my program

You technically did. By including `Python.h`, you effectively include all the headers it is including and depending on. If those are not there, then your code cannot compile. You can find more details on how to properly build around CPython into the [Introduction Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html).

Comment: Yeah,I will check that out